# Where is the compressor run capacitor on my GE refridgerator GTS22WC?

Tags: refrigerator, compressor, capacitor

I have a GE refridgerator GTS22WC, manufactured in 2003.  Both the freezer and fridge are warm.  The compressor doesn't turn on.

I checked the relay resistance (between 5 and 6) and it is 5.5 Ohms and the continuity between 5 and 2 is there. The continuity on the overload is also there.  I measured the resistance on the pins of the compressor and they seem to match what is listed in the circuit diagram.

[image]

Looking at the circuit diagram, I do not see a capacitor for the compressor.  On other appliances there frequently is a capacitor to help start motors.  Looking underneath refrigerator, I don't see one either.

[image]

According to [Appliance Parts Pros](https://www.appliancepartspros.com/search.aspx?model=ge%20gts22wc) there is a run capacitor.  I looked at the circuit board and I don't it there either. The circuit diagram doesn't show it either. [image]

**QUESTION** :

1. Where is the run capacitor for my refrigerator?
2. Since the compressor isn't running, does that mean its either the compressor or the circuit board that is faulty?

Comment: If there was a capacitor, it would be on the wiring diagram. QED, there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your fridge has neither starting nor running capacitor, just like most other modern (post-1980) domestic ones.

In order to be absolutely sure, you can look up the compressor model number, find the compressor datasheet and see if the compressor requires a capacitor.

Chances are it doesn't.

---

If you have a compressor (or any other motor) that requires a capacitor and the capacitor is broken, you will hear a periodic buzz when the motor tries to start, then click of the overload protection, then a minute or two of silence when the overload cools down and then the buzz again.

If this is not the case (and you feel safe dealing with mains AC) you can try powering the compressor directly, bypassing the control circuity. It will most probably flawlessly start and you will continue the debug process elsewhere.